# initiliase list with empty elements python

Tags: python

I am trying to initiliase a list with the first 5 elements empty and then append to the list thereafter. The purpose is that when i write this list to a csv file, the output will be as such: ,,,,,,a,b,c 
here is my code:

```
l = list()
l[:5]=""
l.append('a')
```

When i print out this list, it contains only the element 'a'. How can I initiliase the list such the first 5 elements are empty and when I print it out it will show something like [, , , , , 'a']

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For immutable types like `string` you can do -

```
lst = [""] * 5
```

Though doing this for mutable elements (like lists or so) can cause issues as all the five elements would be pointing to the same object , so mutating one of them would cause changes reflected in the other elements (as they are the same object) .

Answer (score 1):

Use None type.

```
    >>> lst = [None] * 5
    >>> lst.append("a")
    >>> lst
    [None, None, None, None, None, 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do `[ [] ] * 10` the pointer will be copied to all items:

```
>>> a = [[]] * 10
>>> a
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> b = [ [] for i in range(10) ]
>>> b
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
>>> a[0].append(5)
>>> a
[[5], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5], [5]]
>>> b[0].append(5)
>>> b
[[5], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
l = [''] * 5
l.append('a')
print l
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you can:

1. multiply lists to repeat them (e.g. [1, 2] * 2 = [1, 2, 1, 2])
2. add lists together (e.g. [1, 2] + [3, 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4])

Here is a suggested structure:

```
a = 'new item'
l = [''] * 5 + a
>>> l
['', '', '', '', '', 'new item']
```